# Do drives fragment, and if so is there a way to defragment them automatically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-applied-energistics

Let's say I have two drives liked this:

**Drive 1**

- 99 cobble
- 1 wood

**Drive 2**

- 1 cobble
- 99 wood

Now, if I plug both drives into an empty, powered ME drive, would the system be smart enough to automatically consolidated the items to minimize item type count so that drive 1 has 100 cobble and drive 2 has 100 wood?

If this is not possible, is there an easy way to "defragment" these isolated item blocks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The stacks will stay right where they are. The way that I prevent this is by making an [IO Port](http://ftbwiki.org/ME_IO_Port), and sticking the new storage cells with duplicate entries in before connecting it to the network. This is a block that will take any items in a storage cell, and insert them into its network, leaving you with an empty storage cell.